Return maximum number of rows with TOROW() and LAMBDA()
How can I return a maximum number of rows for TOROW(), say 5 rows maximum?
Additionally, how do I declare that it should return the last 5 rows or the first 5 rows?
I've tried to play around with BYROW() and MAX(), but I do not seem to understand how to do this properly.
Any advice would be much appreciated.

=MAP(TOCOL(UNIQUE(Requests!H2:H), 1), LAMBDA(a, {a, TOROW(FILTER({HYPERLINK(IF(Requests!I2:I = "Game", Requests!J2:J, Requests!K2:K), "️")}, Requests!H2:H = a))}))


There are many ways to approach this including the 3 examples below.
MAP
First 5
=MAP(SEQUENCE(5), LAMBDA(seq,   INDEX(UNIQUE(TOCOL(Requests!H2:H,1)), seq)))

INDEX  LAMBDA  MAP  SEQUENCE  TOCOL  UNIQUE
Last 5
=MAP(SEQUENCE(5), LAMBDA(seq,   INDEX(UNIQUE(TOCOL(SORT(Requests!H2:H,ROW(Requests!H2:H), ),1)),seq))) 

INDEX  LAMBDA  MAP  SEQUENCE  SORT  TOCOL  UNIQUE
QUERY
First 5
=QUERY(UNIQUE(Requests!H2:H), "Where Col1 is not Null Limit 5",0)

QUERY  UNIQUE
Last 5
=QUERY(UNIQUE(Requests!H2:H), "Where Col1 is not Null OFFSET "& COUNTA(UNIQUE(Requests!H2:H))-5,0)

COUNTA  QUERY  UNIQUE
CHOOSEROWS
First 5
=CHOOSEROWS(UNIQUE(TOCOL(Requests!H2:H,1)), SEQUENCE(5))

CHOOSEROWS  SEQUENCE  TOCOL  UNIQUE
Last 5
=LET(arr, UNIQUE(TOCOL(Requests!H2:H,1)), 
    CHOOSEROWS(arr, SEQUENCE(1,5,COUNTA(arr)-4)))

CHOOSEROWS  COUNTA  LET  SEQUENCE  TOCOL  UNIQUE
